# Close method calls increments each time I call it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a single page application in plain javascript, I'm not a professional developer yet but I'm looking to learn. Anyway, in my app I have a form from which users will be able to register, and this form will appear as a popup when the user will click the button so I decided to make modal plugin to use it in anther projects if I need it. Everything works fine except every time when I close modal window `close` method calls increments each time.

[image]

Here is the code for close method:

```
close(event) {
    if (event.srcElement !== this.overlay &&
      event.srcElement !== this.closeButton)
      return;
    event.preventDefault()


    const modalLayers = [this.overlay, this.modal]
    const toggleState = element => element.classList.remove('modal-open')

    modalLayers.forEach(toggleState)
    modalLayers.forEach(this._hideOnTransitionEnd)
    this.modal.style.zIndex = -10

    const {
      onClose
    } = this.config
    if (typeof onClose === 'function') onClose.call(this)
    this.isOpen = false
    event.stopPropagation()
}
```

then I have `attachEvents` method

```
attachEvents() {
    const triggers = [this.closeButton, this.overlay]
    const attachTriggers = element =>
      element.addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this))
    triggers.forEach(attachTriggers)
}
```

It is about event bubbling?
I tried to remove the `eventListener` every time the close method was called but didn't work neither

```
const unbind = element => element.removeEventListener('click', this.close)
triggers.forEach(unbind)
```

Full code [here](https://codepen.io/alinmercasi/pen/NWWXapy?editors=0010)

Is there something I miss?
P.S. - sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `open()` method attaches the close listener every time it opens.

```
open() {
    this.attachEvents()
    ...
}
```

You should move that out of the open method. Move it to the build method maybe.

Answer (score 1):

`this.attachEvents` should be called only once and after the Modal is created. Here is called on every open click.

Another try to to unbind the click event first then re-bind.

Answer (score 1):

The `open()` function is attaching the `onClose()` event each time is called. You have to check if `onClose()` has already been attached in order to prevent to call it multiple times.

Something like:

```
open() {
    if(!this.attached){
        this.attachEvents()
    }
    ...
}
```

I have forked and modified your codepen using a simple global variable to check if `attachEvents()` has already been called.

You can check the simple fix [here](https://codepen.io/piraces/pen/WNNdXxW?editors=0011).